# Is Pic( G((z)) ) = $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: loop-groups, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, picard-group

There are a fair number of papers by Beauville, Laszlo, Sorger, Kumar and others on the geometry of $LG/L^+G = G((z))/G[[z]]$ where $G$ is a simply connected and simple group over $\mathbb{C}$.  In particular it is known that $Pic(LG/L^+G)$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$.  The pull back to $LG$ of a generator $1 \in Pic(LG/L^+G)$ is nontrivial and can be chosen so it corresponds to the basic central extension of $LG$.  So $Pic(LG)$ is at least $\mathbb{Z}$ and I think that should be everything.

A divisor for the basic line bundle can be taken to be the complement of $L^-G\cdot L^+G$ where $L^-G = G[z^{-1}]$ so I think the claim would follow if $Pic(L^-G \cdot L^+G) = 0$; but I haven't seen this question addressed in my limited knowledge of the literature.

So is it true that $Pic(LG) = \mathbb{Z}$ and what's a reference that discusses this?